# Tracking possibilities with Magento 1.9 in 2023

Tags: magento, hubspot

I work for a marketing agency. We have a potential new client that has a website on Magento 1.9 and they have said they see no benefit in upgrading. Obviously I'm going to make a strong case for upgrading or ideally migrating to something like WooCommerce, but for now I need to be able to answer the "what can we track" question. They are still just a prospect at this point.

Note: I do not have access to the Magento admin yet, nor do I have hosting access, though I have asked for both and the client is working to get me both. Yet the final sales call is Friday, so I need to be able to tell them what I *think* we can do for them. I'm using BuiltWith to see what the site is using. I cannot tell what the PHP version is.

The client wants to use Hubspot to track metrics, but I cannot tell if we could integrate their old Magento into Hubspot.

Do these sound plausible as tracking I could set up on such an old installation?

1. Google Analytics
2. Google Tag Manager
3. Zapier to feed into Hubspot (Would this work with Magento 1.9?)
4. Hubspot official app for Magento (I'm assuming this won't work with such an old version of Magento?)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding items you have mentioned MissPijon.

- Google Analytics 4 (Basics events will work, e-com events will require some extension)
- Google Tag Manager (Will work)
- Zapier to feed into Hubspot [(Zapier officially support Magento 2 only)](https://zapier.com/apps/magento/integrations)
- Hubspot official app for Magento [(Supports only Magento 2 only)](https://ecosystem.hubspot.com/marketplace/apps/commerce/ecommerce)

Answer (score 0):

I don't perceive any issues with using Magento 1.9, as many of my clients still rely on it. However, I would strongly recommend considering an upgrade to [OpenMage](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts), which provides Continued Long-Term Support (LTS) for Magento 1.

Regarding Google Analytics 4, I've developed a module that offers support for tracking events. You can find more information about it here: https://www.degriz.eu/magento-google-analytics-4-gtag.

And yes you can connect Zapier and Hubspot to Magento 1.9. You can find most of the modules still working for Magento 1.9, maybe some just need some small fixes to work with php 8 that Openmage now supports.